# How to count total occurrence of “@“ In email address in impala hive

Tags: hive, impala

Table A

Clientid                           Email- add
123              Abc@gmail.com

245               Ghi@gm@yahoo.com

I want to find email addresses with count of “@“ > 1.That means i should get clientid 245 as my answer

Comment: You could try using custom hive udfs like [FindStrOccurance](https://github.com/rishuatgithub/hive-custom-udfs/wiki/Find-total-occurance-of-a-word-character-in-a-sentence).

Answer (score 0):

I did not find an Impala function to count occurrences but the below code should work

```
select *
from A
where (length(Email-add) - length(replace(Email-add, '@', ''))) > 1;
```